# Exception isn't caught

Tags: dart

I am having issues with catching exceptions in a flutter app that has lots of `async` and `await`. I came to dart pad to work a few things out and the most simple case got me here.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  try {
    foo();
  } on SocketException {
    print('socket');
  }
}
​
foo() {
  throw SocketException;
}
```

​The expected outcome is to print 'socket' but it gives this error:

> Uncaught Error: SocketException.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with SocketException error. You can read [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/SocketException-class.html) to see for throwing SocketException, you have to have a constructor with a String parameter and you need to instantiate the exception. So if you write the code below, “socket” will be printed.

```
 foo(){
  throw SocketException("message");
 }
```

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_exceptions.htm) link might also help to see how you can catch different exceptions.

From the example below, You can see that if you want to throw an exception, you have to instantiate it first.

```
void main() { 

  try {
     foo();
  } 
  on IntegerDivisionByZeroException { 
     print('Cannot divide by zero'); 
  } 
} 

foo(){
  throw IntegerDivisionByZeroException();
}
```

Comment: Ohh I'm feeling so dumb rn. Thank you

Comment: I didn’t know the exact answer so I searched on google and looked at different questions to find the correct answer. You have to do the same. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to instantiate the object , you are not doing that

**dont**

```
foo() {
  throw SocketException;
}
```

**do**

```
foo() {
  throw SocketException();
}
```

Comment: Also want to add that the constructor for `SocketException` requires one argument: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-io/SocketException-class.html

Comment: Yes that's true, thank you for taking the time to write the answer

Comment: can you vote for the answer and accept that, would appriciate that :), @Hadi

Comment: I'm sorry morez had the answer earlier